# Can't load a javascript file into my page using python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have the following code, put in a file called "showLessMore.js". this file is in the same folder as the python file used to render the webpage:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.shorten = function (settings) {

    var config = {
        showChars: 100,
        ellipsesText: "...",
        moreText: "more",
        lessText: "less"
    };

    if (settings) {
        $.extend(config, settings);
    }

    $(document).off("click", '.morelink');

    $(document).on({click: function () {

            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass('less')) {
                $this.removeClass('less');
                $this.html(config.moreText);
            } else {
                $this.addClass('less');
                $this.html(config.lessText);
            }
            $this.parent().prev().toggle();
            $this.prev().toggle();
            return false;
        }
    }, '.morelink');

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass("shortened")) return;

        $this.addClass("shortened");
        var content = $this.html();
        if (content.length > config.showChars) {
            var c = content.substr(0, config.showChars);
            var h = content.substr(config.showChars, content.length - config.showChars);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + config.ellipsesText + ' </span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span> <a href="#" class="morelink">' + config.moreText + '</a></span>';
            $this.html(html);
            $(".morecontent span").hide();
        }
    });

};

})(jQuery);
```

When I put the code directly in the webpage it works perfect. However, when I try to used the external file "showLessMore.js" as follows it doesn't work:

```
 s.wfile.write('<script src="showLessMore.js"></script>')
```

This is the output in the html page, but when I click on the link of my JS file it doesn't show the file, which is bizarre:

```
      ....
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"><!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript --><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script><script src="showLessMore.js"></script>
....
```

Could you tell me what could be the reason for that ?

Comment: Python does not include a Javascript interpreter (while your browser does:-).

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code? Also what happens exactly? Is that script tag correctly written to your output?

Comment: Does your server serve the `showLessMore.js` file?

Comment: Here is what the server serves: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2015 00:14:43] "GET /showLessMore.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - But I don't know if this is the URL it should serve